# Invalid TNEF Signature when opening Winmail.dat file

Tags: .net, winmail.dat

I have a win mail.dat file. When I try to open it using a winmail reader software, I am getting an error of "Invalid TNEF signature". How can I open this file?

Can anyone please help me to find an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error is because the file is either not a valid TNEF file or because it is corrupted.

Can you attach the file to this post?